# Trying to write to an output file which will be used to print a report. File is being created, but nothing is being written to it

Tags: java

Trying to write to an output file. File is being created, but nothing is being written to it. Problem code is at     outStream.print("525" + " " + svioname + "     ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE AGING  ANALYSIS   ");
    outStream.println (sviostdate+ "     "+ pgcnt);
Thanks for any help.

```
// Statements writer  DLC 1/24/2016
package my.brentair;
import static com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.ExsltDatetime.date;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
//import java.decimal.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.Compiler.command;
import java.text.Format.*;
import java.util.Date.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.D;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.M;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.Y;
import java.util.Formatter.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class aastmnts{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int ioacct, iolpd, iomos, lncnt=0, pgcnt = 1;
double iobal, iocur, io30, io60, io90, iopytd, ioymed, ioyfin, iolpa,                                  iohicred, iocursls, ioytax, ioygrs, ioynet, wkpa, iopbal; 
String ioname, ioconame, ioadr, iocity, iost, iozip, iophone, iosort,      iostdate, iofc, iomail, ionada;
String svioname = null, svioadr, sviocity, sviost, sviozip, sviostdate =    "5/24/13", svioconame=" ";
File outFile = new File("C:\\astmnts.txt");
FileOutputStream outFileStream = null;
    try {
        outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(aastmnts.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,   ex);
    }
PrintWriter  outStream = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);
try     {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection    ( 
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brent?user=root&password=adsimysql");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
//System.out.println("jbtnNAbu ");  
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from " + "bona" +" ");    
System.out.println("aastmnts");
//boolean absolute = rs2.absolute(1); // out because it starts at 2nd record      not first
while (rs2.next()) {      // get name from na file
ioacct = rs2.getInt("nacct");
System.out.println("acct " + ioacct);
iomail = " ";
ioname = rs2.getString("nname");
ioconame = rs2.getString("nconame");
ioadr = rs2.getString("nadr");
iocity = rs2.getString("ncity");
iost = rs2.getString("nst");
iozip = rs2.getString("nzip");
iophone = rs2.getString("nphone");
iosort = rs2.getString("nsort");
iostdate = rs2.getString("nstdate");
iofc = rs2.getString("nfc");
ionada = rs2.getString("nnada");
iobal = rs2 .getDouble("nbal");     //IOBAL CHANGE FROM DOUBLE TO FLOAT
//iobal = Float.parseFloat("nbal");
iocur = rs2.getDouble("ncur");
io30 = rs2.getDouble("n30");
io60 = rs2.getDouble("n60");
io90 = rs2.getDouble("n90");
iopytd = rs2.getDouble("npytd");
ioymed = rs2.getDouble("nymed");
ioytax = rs2.getDouble("nytax");
ioygrs = rs2.getDouble("nygrs");
ioynet = rs2.getDouble("nynet");
ioyfin = rs2.getDouble("nyfin");
iolpd = rs2.getInt("nlpd");
iolpa = rs2.getDouble("nlpa");
iomos = rs2.getInt("nmos");
iohicred = rs2.getDouble("nhicred");
iocursls = rs2.getDouble("ncursls");
iopbal = rs2.getDouble("npbal");
if (ioacct == 1) {svioname = ioname; svioadr = ioadr; sviocity = iocity;    sviozip = iozip;
svioconame = ioconame;
System.out.println("name " + ioname); 
if (0 == lncnt);  {
System.out.println("lncnt " + lncnt); 
outStream.print("525" + " " + svioname + "     ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE AGING  ANALYSIS   ");
outStream.println (sviostdate+ "     "+ pgcnt);  
}  // end lncnt == 0
}  // end ioacct == 1
}  // end while
}  // end try
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {  }
catch(SQLException e) { }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `flush` your output stream.

```
outStream.flush();
```

Or `close` it which will flush automagically:

```
outStream.close();
```